# "Ready when you're." or "Ready when you are."

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Should I follow up the first sentence with the word ready? And if so, why is this so?

Comment: Just say it aloud: it doesn't make any sense. And this is a duplicate.

Comment: Syntactically it's invalid to end such a sentence with a contraction. You could end with *...when you're ready*, but that's not a particularly common form. The standard is *[I'm] ready when you are.*

Comment: The key is stress. Final auxiliary verbs are stressed, but only unstressed auxiliary verbs can be contracted. Consequently, final auxiliary verbs can't be contracted.